# Add Query conditionals to related object's properties in parse.com with JS SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

It is possible to sort and use conditionals to a related object in parse.com?

I have Users which have a pointer to profilePictures. I would like a query such as:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

// include images
query.include("profilePicture");

// get only regular users
query.notEqualTo("isAdmin", true);

// who has uploaded an image
query.exists("profilePicture");

// and such image was updated in the last month
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("profilePicture.updatedAt", today);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("profilePicture.updatedAt", lastMonth);

// and order the resultset by profilePicture.updatedAt
query.ascending("profilePicture.updatedAt");
```

Unfortunatelly this returns a 105 error from parse.com as it can't find the property...

```
{"code":105,"error":"profilePicture.updatedAt is not a valid order key"}
```

All the posts I find are quite old (~2012) and maybe something changed lately. Any idea on how to achieve this?

For sorting I don't really care. I've alrady implemented a comparator, but I need to filter by date as I can't query for 1000's of profiles for nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with `include` and dot-notation. You better use inner queries for this:

```
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query("PICTURES"); // query on your profile picture class
innerQuery.lessThanOrEqualTo("updatedAt", today);
innerQuery.greaterThanOrEqualTo("updatedAt", lastMonth);
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.matchesQuery("profilePicture", innerQuery); // users that match the picture criteria
query.find({
  success: function(users) {
  // You get selected users with the profilePicture criteria
  }
});
```

Comment: well, this actually worked for filtering the results, but doesn't for sorting: innerQuery.ascending("updatedAt") seems to have no effect

Comment: I faced this before. Unfortunately you cannot have sort criteria on an inner query, you need to sort this yourself I am afraid

Comment: Well, filtering was the important thing, thanks again!